# Regular Expression to match string inside parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match all the strings that are enclosed by parentheses. For example for the string below:

```
((5.85B8.5V + ?; 1.79") + (6.78A0 + ?; .97"); 4.760")
```

I want to match ALL of the following:

- 5.85B8.5V + ?; 1.79"
- 6.78A0 + ?; .97"
- (5.85B8.5V + ?; 1.79") + (6.78A0 + ?; .97"); 4.760"

I have never really gotten a hang of regular expressions, so I am having trouble. What I have right now is:

```
pattern = '\((.*?)\)'
m = re.match(pattern, string)
print m.group()
'((5.85B8.5V + ?; 1.79")'
```

That is kind of close, but gets the first parentheses of both types instead of the opening and closing parentheses. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You want stuff inside of parentheses that aren't parentheses... Try `"\(([^()]+)\)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions are bad at parsing nested structures, however, some dialects provide the recursive operator `?R` or `?n` which can help you on that. Python's stock `re` doesn't support it, but fortunately, there is [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module that does:

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = '((5.85B8.5V + ?; 1.79") + (6.78A0 + ?; .97"); 4.760")'
>>> regex.findall(r'(?=(\((?:[^()]|(?1))*\)))', s)
['((5.85B8.5V + ?; 1.79") + (6.78A0 + ?; .97"); 4.760")', '(5.85B8.5V + ?; 1.79")', '(6.78A0 + ?; .97")']
```

That said, regexes are not your best option to parse generic context-free languages (which your string apparently belongs to). Consider using a real parser instead, which you can build with pyParsing or similar package, or just code by hand - that's rather trivial here:

```
def expressions(s):
    stack = []
    for n, c in enumerate(s):
        if c == '(':
            stack.append(n+1)
        elif c == ')':
            yield s[stack.pop():n]

for x in expressions(s):
    print x
```

Comment: PLUS UN, this variant `(?=\(((?:[^()]+|\((?1)\))*+)\))` gives the content of the parenthesis *(without the parenthesis)*

Comment: Agreed. One cannot solve this problem in general with just regular expressions. A simple parser (one that effectively parses S-expressions) is required.

Comment: @MattAnderson: note that the present regex solves the problem in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` but for your inner grouping one time use `r'\(([^()]*)\)'` and one time use `(.*)` (for match the whole of string ) :

```
>>> import pprint
>>> l= re.findall(r'\(([^()]*)\)',s)+re.findall(r'\((.*)\)',s)
>>> pprint.pprint(l)
['5.85B8.5V + ?; 1.79"',
 '6.78A0 + ?; .97"',
 '(5.85B8.5V + ?; 1.79") + (6.78A0 + ?; .97"); 4.760"']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lookarounds inorder to do an overlapping match.

```
>>> s = '((5.85B8.5V + ?; 1.79") + (6.78A0 + ?; .97"); 4.760")'
>>> re.findall(r'(?=\(([^()]*|.*)\))', s)
['(5.85B8.5V + ?; 1.79") + (6.78A0 + ?; .97"); 4.760"', '5.85B8.5V + ?; 1.79"', '6.78A0 + ?; .97"']
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dZ1iN5/6)

We could do an overlapping match through lookarounds only. It's impossible to do without lookarounds. So put your pattern inside a positive lookahead assertion.

`\(([^()]*|.*)\)` `\(` at the first matches a literal `(` symbol. `()` called capturing groups. `[^()]*` matches any char but not of `(` or `)` zero or more times or `|` match any character zero or more times greedily `.*` upto the last `\)` symbol.